# how implement setPagesize for pagination, right now returning all products

Tags: magento

All I am trying to setPageSize() on collection so that I can use that for Pagination.

I am getting all the products returned no matter what integer I put into the setPageSize.

Code:

```
    <?php

class Rik_Featured_Block_Featured extends
Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    private $_itemPerPage = 2;
    public $_category_id = '' ;
    private $_currentPage = '';

    public function __construct() {
        $custom_var_code = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('homepage_firstrow_prod');
        if(isset($custom_var_code)) echo $this->_category_id = $custom_var_code->getValue('text') ;
        echo $page_var = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p');
        if(isset($page_var)&&$page_var!=0){           
            $this->_currentPage = $page_var;
        }
        if(isset($page_var)&&$page_var == '0'){           
            $this->_currentPage = '1';
        }


    }


    /****************** Here is my setcurpage and setpagesize************************/

        public function allProducts() {
        $collection = $this->_getCollection();
        echo 'col is'.$collection->count();
        /*Setting current page and page size */
        $collection->setCurPage(1);
        $collection->setPageSize($this->_itemPerPage);
        return $collection;
    }

        private function _getCollection() {

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->_category_id);

        if($category->getUrlPath() != NULL) {

            $collection = $category->getProductCollection();


            //Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
            $collection->addWebsiteFilter();
            $collection->addUrlRewrite($this->_category_id);
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()->addFinalPrice()->addTaxPercents();
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
                    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id', 'sku', 'name', 'short_description', 
                'description', 'price', 'thumbnail', 'image', 'url_path', 'type_of'));

           return $collection;
        }
        else { echo 'cat does not exit';}
      }




    public function totalPages() {       

        $_collections_count = $this->_getCollection()->count();
        return $number_of_pages = ceil($_collections_count / $this->_itemPerPage);
    }



}
```

Also is it a good idea to use the __constructor the way I am using in this block?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In reverse order:

First, never use PHP's `__construct` with Magento's blocks or models, especially without calling the parent `__construct`.  Use Magento's `_construct` instead. *(note the underlines)*

Second, you're calling the correct pagination methods.  If you simplify your code a little,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection();                      

$collection->setCurPage(1);
$collection->setPageSize(10);

$i=1;
foreach($collection as $item)
{
    var_dump($i . ') ' . $item->getSku());
    $i++;
}
```

it's easy to see the `setCurPage` and `setPageSize` methods work as expected.

```
//results of running above code
string '1) n2610' (length=8)
string '2) bb8100' (length=9)
string '3) sw810i' (length=9)
string '4) 8525PDA' (length=10)
string '5) MM-A900M' (length=11)
string '6) MA464LL/A' (length=12)
string '7) LX.FR206.001' (length=15)
string '8) VGN-TXN27N/B' (length=15)
string '9) M285-E' (length=9)
string '10) cn_3' (length=8)
```

The problem is your call to `count`

```
$collection = $this->_getCollection();
echo 'col is'.$collection->count();
/*Setting current page and page size */
$collection->setCurPage(1);
$collection->setPageSize($this->_itemPerPage);
return $collection;
```

To count a product collection, Magento must load the entire collection, (The loading logic is too complicated for a simple `SELECT count(*)`).  Because you're calling count **before** you set the page information, Magento loads a full collection before it's aware of the page restrictions.

You can fix this by not calling `count`, or `clear`ing the collection before looping. Try the following code, both with and without the `$collection->clear();`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection();                      

$collection->load();
$collection->setCurPage(1);
$collection->setPageSize(10);   
$collection->clear();
$i=1;
foreach($collection as $item)
{
    var_dump($i . ') ' . $item->getSku());
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: As @Alan mentioned, `$collection->count()` will load all items and doing count. To get number of records of collection, you should use `$collection->getSize()` instead. `$collection->getSize()` use `SELECT count(*)..`

Comment: Once again you saved my life Alan ; nice tip ndlinh!